# INSERT row based on relationship MYSQL

Tags: mysql, insert

I have the following scenario in my mysql database. 2 tables:

**todoitems**

- todo_id
- todo_title

**todo_sync_controllers**

- todo_sync_id
- device_id
- should_delete
- is_deleted
- todo_id

As you can see there is a one-to-many relationship from todoitems to todo_sync_controllers.

I comunicate with the server using php script. Every time I do a fetch from a device of the todo items I need to make sure there is a todo_sync_controller entry for that device and todo item. If it is missing it should be created.

One way to solve this is to use loops and multiple queries from my php-script but I was wondering if this can be accomplished using a single INSERT query? Any ideas?

Comment: Why not create a unique key of device_id and todo_id and then do a insert query everytime? Only first time the query will succeed.

Comment: so basically you wanna select data if exist other wise insert.

Comment: @somnath: How would the insert statement look? Wouldn't this mean that I still have to loop through all the todoitems and perform the INSERT query for each todo_id?

Comment: @PrashantShukla: I don't need to SELECT the todo_sync_controller, i just want to insert it if it doesnt exist for that device_id and todoitem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your solution is pretty simple just make unique key for todo_id and device_id in your todo_sync_controllers table so when ever you make insert to table from your script it will check for unique constraint and if it not exist, will insert data otherwise ignoed with mysql error to query. If you wanna check whether your data inserted or just ignored because of duplicate key, you need to apply if condition while making query and if it returns true means insertion is done otherwise ignored by system.This will be done like below code

```
if(mysql_query($sql_query)){
    echo "your data inserted";
}else{
    echo "data already exist";
}
```

and alter your table with

```
create unique index on todo_sync_controllers (todo_id ,device_id)
```